# To much green pepper in my chili, can I fix it?

Tags: chili, bell-peppers

Can I fix it? What can I add, everything I see says about pepper. It has to much green pepper in it.

Comment: Is the pepper chopped? So finely that you can't just pick it out? Have you added the beans yet - maybe you could use extra.

Comment: Yes it is chopped very fine. Added everything to it already.

Comment: What is wrong with just cooking a batch with too much green pepper?   Add more beans?

Comment: Green chile peppers, or green peppercorn?

Comment: Spicy hot green, or the mild stuff? Longer cooking will reduce the heat of hot peppers, dilution will cut down on too many bells, at the expense of giving you a larger batch of chili.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Ended adding tomato paste and sugar and more chili powder and it was great!

Answer (score 4):

1. Add more of the other ingredients
2. Add dairy
3. Add acid
4. Add a sweetener
5. Serve with bland, starchy foods

Options 1 and 5 provide a solution which will not alter the flavor of your chili too much.

Source of ideas: [The Kitchn](http://www.thekitchn.com/6-ways-to-tone-down-a-dish-thats-too-spicy-223776)

Comment: Thank you! I added more tomato paste, and some sugar and more chili powder and it was great!

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by "Too much green pepper".

Too much bell pepper and the chili is not spicy/hot enough?

- Add more hot peppers, adjust other aromatics/spices to be proportional - don't recommend adding more meat/beans)

Too much of some other chili and it's too spicy/hot?

- Serve with rice or other bland starch; add more of not-spicy ingredients to dilute)

Pepper mix out of balance and doesn't have the flavor that you want?

- Add other peppers to balance, probably adjust meat/beans and other aromatics/spices to be proportional).